# Нужная ли запятая в предложении "Сукно зелёное 2 м)?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в предложении по модели: "Сукно зелёное(,) 2 метра"?

Или так: "Сукно зелёное(,) отрез (-) 2 метра".

Спасибо!